# Issue with looping through columns in perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I'm having issues with a script I've written. I've broken it down to identify the problem and here it is.

Input file (tab delimited):

```
FORMAT  Sample1        Sample2        Sample3
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:17,6:23:85:85,0,370 0/0:51,6:57:17:0,17,1359        0/0:3,0:3:9:0,9,99
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0:3,0:3:0:.:.:0,0,38  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/1:1,2:3:26:0|1:13813_T_G:81,0,26
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  ./.:2,0:2:.:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/1:1,2:3:26:0|1:13813_T_G:81,0,26
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0       1/1:0,4:4:12:131,12,0   ./.:0,0:0:.:0,0,0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0        0/0:3,0:3:9:.:.:0,9,98  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,30
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0        0/0:3,0:3:9:.:.:0,9,98  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,30
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0        0/0:3,0:3:9:.:.:0,9,98  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,30
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1:0,2:2:6:1|1:14590_G_A:90,6,0        0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,72  0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,30
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,7:7:21:186,21,0   0/1:5,4:9:79:79,0,103   ./.:1,0:1:.:0,0,0
```

Desired output (take the first 3 characters before the colon from each sample) per line and print each line:

```
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1 0/0       0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0  0/0  0/1
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  ./.   0/0  0/1
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./.       1/1   ./.
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1        0/0  0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1       0/0  0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1       0/0  0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  1/1      0/0  0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1   0/1  ./.
```

The code I'm using to do this step is not producing the correct 0/0, 0/1, 0/2 codes as expected per line. I think it is an issue with how I've written the for loop but I'm not sure.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $inputfile1 = $ARGV[0];
open (FILE1, $inputfile1) or die "Uh oh.. unable to find file $inputfile1"; ##Opens input file

my @file1 = <FILE1>; #loads inputfile1 data into array
close FILE1;


my (@colsplit, @genotypes1, @genotypes2, @genotypes3, @joined); 
foreach my $line(@file1) { ## process each line, splitting columns and move onto next line
    @colsplit = split("\t", $line);
        push (@joined, $colsplit[0]);
            foreach my $lines(@colsplit) {
                if ($colsplit[1] =~ m/(^0\/1)/ || $colsplit[1] =~ m/(^0\/0)/ || $colsplit[1]=~ m/(^1\/0)/ || $colsplit[1] =~ m/(^1\/1)/ || $colsplit[1] =~ m/(^.\/.)/) {
                    push (@genotypes1, $1);
                    }
                    if ($colsplit[2] =~ m/(^0\/1)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^0\/0)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^1\/0)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^1\/1)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^.\/.)/) {
                    push (@genotypes2, $1);
                    }
                    if ($colsplit[3] =~ m/(^0\/1)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^0\/0)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^1\/0)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^1\/1)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^.\/.)/) {
                    push (@genotypes3, $1); 
                    }       
                }
            }



my $i = 0;
foreach my $line(@joined) {
    if ($line =~ m/GT/) {
print "$line\t$genotypes1[$i]\t$genotypes2[$i]\t$genotypes3[$i]\n";
$i++;
    }}
```

I think the issue may be that once the first sample1 column is matched, it jumps to the second line rather than iterating through the second sample2 column. I can't see how I'm messing this up otherwise! It's driving me nuts!

My current output is:

```
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1 0/0 0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/1 0/0 0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/1 0/0 0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1 0/0 0/0
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0 0/0 0/1
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0 0/0 0/1
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0 0/0 0/1
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0 0/0 0/1
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  ./. 0/0 0/1
```

This is clearly not what I want!

Any help would be gratefully received.

Ps. I'm new to this so go easy.

Comment: Use PyVCF or another library for VCF parsing rather rolling out your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems clear, to keep data before `:` in each column (except in the first). But then I am a little confused by the attempted code, which needlessly goes through specific patterns for columns.

Here is a simple take on what is described

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $header_line = <>;   # drop the first line

while (<>) {            # line by line from files given on cmdline, or STDIN
    chomp;

    my ($fmt_col, @cols) = split /\t/;   # (but sample has spaces, not tabs)

    s/(.*?):.*/$1/ for @cols;            # keep up to (first) : in each field
    
    say join "\t", $fmt_col, @cols;      # print fields joined by tabs
}
```

The `<>` reads all lines from all files given on the command-line, or `STDIN`; so submit a filename to process on the command line when running this program.

Note that the posted sample doesn't have tabs, but rather spaces; so the above code will fail if one copy-pastes it.  Either change spaces to tabs to test, or change `split /\t/;`  to `split;` (so to use its default to split on, which is any amount of any whitespace).

All fields other than the first are changed so that only characters up to the first `:` stay.

This is done using the fact that each item processed in the `foreach` loop ("topicalizer") is aliased to the currently processed element.  So when the regex `s///` changes it then the corresponding element of `@cols` is changed.  If this seems too cooky to stomach please by all means write it out nice and slow.

If something else is actually needed to do please clarify.

Comment: thank you. Couple of things of note:

1) I can't just use the 3 characters before the first colon rule, as I specifically need to pull out situations when it is `0/0` `0/1` `1/1` `./.` only (excluding other options) and then the next part of my code takes these inputs and then gives them a name depending on whether they are `0/0` etc. That's why I used the regex to pull out the specific notation and then the code afterwards translates that accordingly.

Comment: @lecb I see, that explains it.  I'll add to this answer as I get to it/  (Then what to do with fields which don't have those particular patterns?  Just leave them as they are?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed the issue. I removed `foreach my $lines(@colsplit) {` and now it works! Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $inputfile1 = $ARGV[0];
open (FILE1, $inputfile1) or die "Uh oh.. unable to find file $inputfile1"; ##Opens input file

my @file1 = <FILE1>; #loads inputfile1 data into array
close FILE1;


my (@colsplit, @genotypes1, @genotypes2, @genotypes3, @joined); 
foreach my $line(@file1) { ## process each line, splitting columns and move onto next line
    @colsplit = split("\t", $line);
        push (@joined, $colsplit[0]);
                if ($colsplit[1] =~ m/(^0\/1)/ || $colsplit[1] =~ m/(^0\/0)/ || $colsplit[1]=~ m/(^1\/0)/ || $colsplit[1] =~ m/(^1\/1)/ || $colsplit[1] =~ m/(^.\/.)/) {
                    push (@genotypes1, $1);
                    }
                    if ($colsplit[2] =~ m/(^0\/1)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^0\/0)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^1\/0)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^1\/1)/ || $colsplit[2] =~ m/(^.\/.)/) {
                    push (@genotypes2, $1);
                    }
                    if ($colsplit[3] =~ m/(^0\/1)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^0\/0)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^1\/0)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^1\/1)/ || $colsplit[3] =~ m/(^.\/.)/) {
                    push (@genotypes3, $1); 
                }
            }



my $i = 0;
foreach my $line(@joined) {
    if ($line =~ m/GT/) {
print "$line\t$genotypes1[$i]\t$genotypes2[$i]\t$genotypes3[$i]\n";
$i++;
    }}
```

Thanks to @zdim especially for showing me a more elegant solution.
E

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use the [continuation modifier (`c`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Other-Modifiers) of regular expression matching. It causes a matching operation to start from where the last one found a match. Like that, each field of a line can be processed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh;
$ARGV[0] && open($fh, $ARGV[0]) || die();

# discard first line;
<$fh>;

foreach my $line (<$fh>) {
  chomp($line);

  # capture every non tab character from the beginning of the line;
  # globally match the pattern repeatedly in the string (g modifier)
  # keep the current position during repeated matching (c modifier);
  $line =~ m/^([^\t]*)/gc;
  print("$1");

  # capture every non colon character after a tab character;
  # globally match the pattern repeatedly in the string (g modifier);
  # keep the current position during repeated matching (c modifier);
  while ($line =~ m/\t([^:]*)/gc) {
    print("\t$1");
  }

  print("\n");
}
```